# Attach item data to a menu item

Tags: c++, mfc, menuitem

This is a work in progress for creating a context menu:

```
CMenu   mnuContext;
CMenu   *pMnuPopup, *pMnuSwap;

mnuContext.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_MWB_SWAP);
pMnuPopup = mnuContext.GetSubMenu(0);
if (pMnuPopup != nullptr)
{
    pMnuSwap = pMnuPopup->GetSubMenu(0);
    if (pMnuSwap != nullptr)
    {
        CMenu *pMnuChairman = pMnuSwap->GetSubMenu(0);
        if (pMnuChairman != nullptr)
            pMnuChairman->DeleteMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION);
        //#TODO Init other pop up menus

        int iChairman = -1; // Reset counters
        for (int i = 0; i < m_cbDates.GetCount(); i++)
        {
            CString strDate, strMenuText;
            m_cbDates.GetLBText(i, strDate);

            CChristianLifeMinistryEntry *pEntry = static_cast<CChristianLifeMinistryEntry*>(m_cbDates.GetItemDataPtr(i));
            if (pEntry->GetChairman() != _T("") && pMnuChairman != nullptr && i != m_iDateIndex)
            {
                iChairman++;
                strMenuText = pEntry->GetChairman() + _T(" (") + strDate + _T(")");
                pMnuChairman->InsertMenu(iChairman, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_SWAP_CHAIRMAN_ITEM + iChairman, strMenuText);
                //# TODO Can I assign the pointer of pEntry? Or the "i" variable?
            }
        }

        pMnuPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON,
            pMsg->pt.x, pMsg->pt.y, this, nullptr);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am creating a menu item like this:

```
pMnuChairman->InsertMenu(iChairman, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_SWAP_CHAIRMAN_ITEM + iChairman, strMenuText);
```

Is it possible for me to associate with this menu item the `i` variable? Either that, or the the actual pointer (`pEntry`)?

Comment: `CMenu::SetMenuItemInfo` or `CMenu::InsertMenuItem` will set `MENUITEMINFO::dwItemData` This can be useful in an owner draw menu, which you don't seem to have. The menu only reports the menu ID through the message map. Other values are not reported. You could use `GetMenuItemInfo` to extract data from the menu - assuming the menu is not destroyed and `MENUITEMINFO` is not changed - but that's very messy. I think `std::map` is a better option here.

Comment: You might consider `int result = menu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_RETURNCMD|..., ...)` This will return the menu result in the same function, instead of going around in a message loop. It will be easier to access item data associated with that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you need to associate the menu item with the variable `i`. I think what you need instead is to handle the messages when the dynamic menu item is clicked. For a static menu item you would use [`ON_COMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5f1bcxd.aspx) and [`ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8c866kb.aspx) macros in your message map.

What you can do in your case is to use the [`ON_COMMAND_RANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab3z9tb.aspx) in your message map to have a single handler for the range of menu items:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CYourView, CFormView)
  ON_COMMAND_RANGE(ID_SWAP_CHAIRMAN_ITEM, ID_SWAP_CHAIRMAN_ITEM + 100, OnChairmanClick)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Your `OnChairmanClick` function will have this syntax:

```
void CYourView::OnChairmanClick(UINT nID)
```

You will need to remember the UID of the menu item you associated with a chairman, e.g. in your `CChristianLifeMinistryEntry` you can add an UID member for it. You can also create a `CMap<UID, CChristianLifeMinistryEntry, UID, CChristianLifeMinistryEntry>` where you would store the UIDs for a quicker access.

Comment: I know about the command range and will be using it. I wanted to store the I value so that in the range handler I can get the pEntry from the CComboBox itemdata pointer at the I index. Then I can do my action which is to swap values.

Comment: In this case create a CMap where you can associate the UID of the item with the i: `CMap<UINT, int, UINT, int>`, where the key is the UID of the menu and the value is the `i` value. Then in the handler you will locate the i from the UID

Comment: Actually the menu ID as you say becomes the index when I subtract the base menu ID in the range handler. So I know which index it was any way. 

Comment: It seems though you use SetMenuItemInfo to set item data though.